# Pass URL as request String

Tags: spring, url, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to pass URL as a request parameter to a Spring Rest controller but I am getting an empty string.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response getMessage(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("url") String url){}
```

Comment: Can you post your jsp or whichever file you are using for view?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getRequestURL()` method of your `HttpServletRequest` object, i.e. `request` to get the URL of your request.
If you are trying to pass another URL as a parameter, revisit your view file and ensure that the correct parameter is being passed to your controller method.